# Play Framework CORS request

Tags: playframework, cors

I have two apps:

1. Play 2.6.7 app running at localhost:9000
2. webpack dev server that runs at localhost:3000

The webpack app makes a POST request to the Play app

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:9000/users',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  dataType: 'json',
  method: 'POST'
})
```

To which the Play app responds with

```
Failed to load http://localhost:9000/users: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Only when I explicitly set the header in the Play app with

```
def create = Action { 
  Ok("stuff").withHeaders(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "http://localhost:3000"
  )
}
```

does the request go through without error.

My question is: why doesn't Play set this header automatically as the [docs](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.7/CorsFilter) seem to suggest? My `application.conf` is an empty file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CORS filter isn't enabled by default. Adding

```
play.filters.enabled += play.filters.cors.CORSFilter
```

to application.conf solves this issue

Comment: Here is a working example. https://github.com/techmonad/play-cors-example